# Codeigniter, Session Cookie not sent to server?

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, session-cookies, codeigniter-3

I am trying to output the cookies I get from the user, when I open the network section in the **Developer Tools**,if I open the  request I find the cookie in the **Request Headers**, but when I am output the cookie

```
$this->input->cookie();
```

I am getting;

```
array(0) { }
```

Session Config

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/ci_sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Cookies Config

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

I am using **Codeigniter 3.0.0**, OS **Fedora 27**, Server **Apache** I tried this on different browsers, **Chrome** and **Firefox**

[Request Headers and Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51YN3.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think if you want to output the cookie, you need to do so by name. So, based on your image,  `$this->input->cookie('ci_session')` or  `$this->input->cookie('ci_session', TRUE)`. [Check this article for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409994/how-to-retrieve-cookie-value-in-codeigniter).

Comment: Also...are you loading the cookie helper in the controller or via autoload?

Comment: If you want to get the ci_session value, just use `session_id()`

Comment: It's great to see how you're checking for cookie contents, but without seeing how you are setting the cookie, then how would we know what's going on? Please add your cookie related config and code showing how you are setting the cookie.

Comment: @BrianGottier I added the configuration, and to be specific what I am having problem with is the session's cookie, which is being regenerated each time I make a request.

@cfnerd I am loading using the autoload, and I if I did var_dump() or print_r() for `$this->input->cookie()` I will see all the cookies including the **ci_session**

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problem was replacing my Session folder with a new one from a newer version of Codeigniter.

System -> libraries -> **Sesssion**