# session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user with PHP 7.3 fedora 31

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3, fedora

I am working on a project which uses codeigniter 3.1.11 as base. It is 90% completed and the development environment is Ubuntu 18.04 with php 7.2.

Due to some other issues, I am happened to switch to Fedora, I have configured php 7.3.16 with all the other LAMP stack.

I am facing a issue in my code igniter as follows

> session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: /var/www/html/apps/guest_house/assets/sessions)

Where as my session configs goes like

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'iisertvm_guest_house';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH.'/assets/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Where as the sessions directory has 777.

I have found similar issue, but the solution is to upgrade to the latest Codeingiter and php, 
where as I am in latest codeigniter and php.

Note : The same source files run flawlessly in my workplace server which has Cent OS 6 with PHP 5.6

I am new to RedHat based distro where Ubuntu has been my home for several years.

Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please **edit** and show why this is not a duplicate....

Comment: Can you confirm that your full path exist?

Comment: Can you confirm that *every* part of the path is accessible as 777? It's nice if `sessions` is 777, but if any part of the path before that is not accessible to the webserver that doesn't help.

Comment: Also it looks like you're storing the session data within the public html folder area, that is publically accessible..... this isn't good at all from a security perspective....

Comment: Yes.. I have made entire /var/www/html as 777 to make sure that it is writable by php, also the owner of the path /var/www/html/ is apache

Comment: @Martin Thank you for the suggestion, it is 777 only in my development machine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235177/codeigniter-session-cookie-not-sent-to-server

Comment: @Martin Yes the path exist, It runs flawlessly in ubuntu 18.04 with php 7.2

Answer (score 1):

Now the problem is fixed.
Earlier SElinux mode was enforcing
After setting it to permissive it works fine.