# How to get current session cookie value in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Anybody has any idea how to get $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] value in codigniter, which will be remain same unless browser close? 
Thanks

Comment: No i don't want this. What i want to get is the current browser session which will be remain unchanged unless closing the browser.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the session id you first need to verify on application/config/config.php the value for the variable `sess_cookie_name`. You will find something like:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
```

As mentioned on this issue [How to retrieve cookie value in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409994/how-to-retrieve-cookie-value-in-codeigniter), you get the cookie using the code:

```
$cookies = $this->input->cookie();
```

In the cookies variable you have all the cookies from your application. In order to get the session id from the above you do:

```
$session_id = $cookies->ci_session;
```

If you just need the session id you can get it directly using the [get_cookie](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/cookie_helper.html#get_cookie) function from the [cookie_helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/cookie_helper.html):

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
$session_id = get_cookie('ci_session');
```

Comment: thanks Francisco for your reply, but in your approach will the value of ci_session be same unless i close the browser window?

Comment: The session could remain the same even if you close the browser because the browser can save this information in cache. Codeignier only creates a new session when there is not a valid one to be used. For instance, the session timeout or the user clear the browse cache. it those cases Codeigniter will generate a new session.

Toton, I advise you to read the Session documentation: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session
Codeginiter documentation is really good and give you all the information you need.